# entropy change in a irreversible adiabatic process

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider I have a gas in insulated cylinder fitted with a piston. I expand the gas inside the cylinder, compress it rapidly and move the piston randomly and finally bring the system to its initial state. Here entropy change is zero. But during an irreversible cycle Q<0. How could this be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem very confused. If you impose an irreversible process on your adiabatic system like that, you won't be able to bring the system back to its initial state. You will be able to bring it back to its initial volume, but not at the same initial temperature and pressure. The entropy change will certainly not be zero. it will be greater than zero. (What makes you think it would be zero?). During the irreversible adiabatic cycle, Q = 0. That's what adiabatic means